# v8 on mac includes malware？

Tags: node.js, macos, v8

I use Comodo antivirus scan my mac and found that there are some threads.

All are marked with name:

```
UnclassifiedMalware@290428014
```

for file

```
string-replace-gc.js
```

Just wonder if Comodo makes mistake or there is something infects V8?

Your comment welcome

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a test that doesn't even get executed normally.

So I'd bet it's a false positive. You can compare that with [github](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/deps/v8/test/mjsunit/string-replace-gc.js) if you want.